# Is this the right way to use Callable?

Tags: java, rest, executorservice, callable

I have a big text file to be processed. The method parse() is trying to use multiple threads to send requests to a restful service to get back  results. For each inputInfo, it should return an ExtractedInfo after the processing.

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);


public ExtractedInfo parse(InputInfo inputInfo) {
    ExtractedInfo extractedInfo = new ExtractedInfo();
    String inputText = inputInfo.getText();

    Callable<String> parseTask = () -> this.executeTask(inputText);
    Future<String> parseService = executorService.submit(parseTask);

    String result = null;
    try {

        result = parseService.get(Parameters.getParserTimeLimit(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("ExecutionException | InterruptedException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException te) {
        parseService.cancel(true);
        LOGGER.warn("NLP parser time out for {} {} {}", sku, inputText, msgId);
    }

    if (result != null) {
        extractedInfo.setResult(result);
    }

    return extractedInfo;
}
```

The private method "executeTask" is sending requests to a restful service which is handled by a python application.

```
 private String executeTask(String inputText) {
    String jsonOutput = null;
    String urlStr = null;
    try {
        String encodedInputText = URLEncoder.encode("\"" + inputText + "\"", "UTF-8");
        urlStr = parserServerSelection();
        URL url = new URL(urlStr + encodedInputText);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        jsonOutput = in.readLine();
        in.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonOutput;
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Not really. If you call get immediately you just sit and block.

Comment: @NathanHughes how to modify it to work?